# Getting output from a PHP shuffle and INSERT into new database table

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I have the code below that shuffles the output of the users in my 'users' table. I want to be able to send the shuffled results to a new db table in the order that the shuffle sorted the results. I am wanting each sorted result to create a new row in my db.

I'm not sure how I can grab the results of the PHP shuffle and send it. I added in a new submit input, so when the results have been shown, the user can submit the results. The results can not be inserted during the shuffling process, it has to be after the results have been outputted.

How can I get the results from the shuffle and INSERT them? I just want to see how I can get my current results.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "db");
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` = 3");

echo 'Normal results: <br>';
$array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[] = $row;
    echo $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '<br>';
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Shuffle" name="shuffle">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['shuffle'])) {
    shuffle($array);
    echo 'Shuffled results: <br>';
    foreach ($array as $result) {
    $shuffle_firstname = $result['firstname'];
    $shuffle_lastname = $result['lastname'];
?>

<div id="shuffle_results">
        <?php echo $shuffle_firstname . ' ' . $shuffle_lastname . '<br>';?>
</div>
 <?php   }
}
 //What the new submit button will be like
 <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Insert to db" name="insert">
    </form>
```

UPDATE: ADDED PREPARED STATEMENT

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` = 3");

echo 'Normal results: <br>';
$array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[] = $row;
    echo $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '<br>';
}
?>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Shuffle" name="shuffle">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['shuffle'])) {
    shuffle($array);
    echo 'Shuffled results: <br>';
    foreach ($array as $result) {
    $shuffle_id = $result['id'];
    $shuffle_firstname = $result['firstname'];
    $shuffle_lastname = $result['lastname'];
?>

<div id="shuffle_results">
     <?php echo '<ol>' . '<li>' . $shuffle_firstname . ' ' . $shuffle_lastname . '</li>' . '</ol>' . '<br>';?>
</div>
 <?php   }

}
($user->lastId);
    var_dump($user->insert_id);

if (isset($_POST['shuffle'])) {
    shuffle($array);
    ?>
    Shuffled results:<br>
    <form method="post">
    <?php
    foreach ($array as $result) {
        $shuffle_id = htmlentities($result['id']);
        $shuffle_firstname = htmlentities($result['firstname']);
        $shuffle_lastname = htmlentities($result['lastname']);
        $shuffle_username = htmlentities($result['username']);
        $shuffle_email = htmlentities($result['email']);

        ?>
        <div class="shuffle_results"><?php echo $shuffle_firstname . ' ' . $shuffle_lastname; ?></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_firstname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_lastname; ?>">
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Insert to db" name="insert">
    </form>
    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_players (user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    if ( false===$stmt2 ) {
         // Check Errors for prepare
        die('Add to user players prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    $stmt2->bind_param('issss', $shuffle_id, $shuffle_firstname, $shuffle_lastname, $shuffle_username, $shuffle_email);
    if ( false===$stmt2 ) {
    // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('Add to user players bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
    }
    $stmt2->execute();
    if ( false===$stmt2 ) {
        die('Add to user players execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the shuffled names in `<input type="hidden">` fields in the form.

```
if (isset($_POST['shuffle'])) {
    shuffle($array);
    ?>
    Shuffled results:<br>
    <form method="post">
    foreach ($array as $result) {
        $shuffle_firstname = htmlentities($result['firstname']);
        $shuffle_lastname = htmlentities($result['lastname']);
        $shuffle_id = htmlentities($result['id']);
        $shuffle_username = htmlentities($result['username']);
        $shuffle_email = htmlentities($result['email']);

        ?>
        <div class="shuffle_results"><?php echo $shuffle_firstname . ' ' . $shuffle_lastname; ?></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_firstname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_lastname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_username; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_email; ?>">
        <?php
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Insert to db" name="insert">
    </form>
}
```

When this form is submitted, `$_POST['firstname']` and `$_POST['lastname']` will be arrays, so you can loop through them and insert them into the new table.

```
if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_players (user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    if ( false===$stmt2 ) {
         // Check Errors for prepare
        die('Add to user players prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    $stmt2->bind_param('issss', $shuffle_id, $shuffle_firstname, $shuffle_lastname, $shuffle_username, $shuffle_email);

    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i => $shuffle_id) {
        $shuffle_firstname = $_POST['firstname'][$i];
        $shuffle_lastname = $_POST['lastname'][$i];
        $shuffle_username = $_POST['username'][$i];
        $shuffle_email = $_POST['email'][$i];
        $stmt2->execute() or
            die('Add to user players execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
    }
}
```

Note that you should use a class rather than ID for the `shuffle_results` DIV, because you're adding one for each row in the results. IDs have to be unique.

You could also just put `$result['id']` in the `insert` form, without all the other hidden inputs. Then the script that processes it can get the other fields from the `users` table and inser them into `user_players`.

```
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_players (user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email)
                        SELECT user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email
                        FROM users 
                        WHERE id = ?");
$stmt2->bind_param("i", $shuffle_id);
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $shuffle_id) {
    $stmt2->execute() or die('Add to user players execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
}
```

Comment: Well I am going to want to make a new form for this `<input type="submit" value="Insert to db" name="insert">` . So when that form isset I want to send the results from the shuffle.

Comment: Isn't that the form in my answer?

Comment: Ok, so I just added my query to this and it is only sending the first user in the outputted shuffle results. I need this to send all of the users that were shuffled, each in their own row. I will update my question to show my code.

Comment: Did you remember to put `[]` at the end of the names? That's what creates the array in `$_POST`.

Comment: Edit your question, not my answer.

Comment: In my prepared statement add those?

Comment: No, in the form. `name="firstname[]"`.

Comment: Wow.. I was wondering why the edit was so weird. Sorry about that, never messed up doing that before. I added my code to my question.

Comment: Yes, I have the [] like you do. I added in `<input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_username; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_email; ?>">` because I noticed I didn't have those. I have no idea why else this isn't adding in everyone?

Comment: I don't see any code in your update that does `if(isset($_POST['insert']))` to process the insert form.

Comment: You're doing the `INSERT` when you shuffle the array, not when the user submits the form.

Comment: And you're doing it outside the `foreach ($array as $result)` loop, so you're just getting the last row.

Comment: If I put the closing bracket for the foreach statement after my prepared statement, I get the same user added in for as many users as I have. Not all the diffferent users. How can I get the `INSERT` to take place with the insert to database submit button?

Comment: BTW, what makes you think this is shuffling in the database? Database entries aren't ordered by the time they're inserted, the only ordering is based on using `ORDER BY` in queries. You're not changing the IDs, so they're in the same order.

Comment: I don't want it to shuffle in the database. I want to shuffle outside the database and then send the shuffled results to another database to randomize user's order for something. I'll try out your update.

Comment: What I mean is that the idea of "shuffled" doesn't even make sense in a database. There's no ordering except that defined by the values of the data.

Comment: The order that you do the `INSERT` queries makes no difference to the database, so shuffling them before inserting doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Unless you have an `auto_increment` column in the new table, and later you'll use that for ordering. That column contains the order that they were inserted.

Comment: Yes, I have an auto increment id for ordering purposes. Then I have a user_id column that will allow me to pull other info from my users table for them later on with different things. I modified my code with your suggestions and it worked perfectly. I did not mess with the third part to your answer as I could tell I was already getting the info from my users table. Thanks!

Comment: You should also think about whether you even need to have those fields in the `user_players` table in the first place. It should just contain the `user_id`, and when you use it you can join with `users` to get all the details.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to combine queries with different tables yet. But this is a small site that will have hardly any traffic on it. It is actually a private site that I'm testing out this year and hopefully going to market it next year and expand to take on lots of users.

Comment: If you expect to be doing any non-trivial work with databases you need to learn how to write joins.

Comment: Thanks. Thay is actually my project over the weekend to try to learn because my task list ahead of my is a lot of queries relating to my users table with other ones and that will definitely help. I didn't even know what it was called to do it, so that helps.